# Appium No route found for /session/48cb46ad-f1ab-42c2-97e0-6aab7117705a/appium/compare_images

Tags: image, testing, mobile, comparison, appium

I'm trying to perform partial comparing of pictures using example from this page "Occurrences Lookup"
https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/writing-running-appium/image-comparison/

I'm using this lines of code

```
    byte[] expectedPartialImage = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    byte[] fullActualImage = Base64.encodeBase64(commonCucumberStep.getUiRunner().getAndroidDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
    OccurrenceMatchingResult result = commonCucumberStep.getUiRunner().getAndroidDriver()
            .findImageOccurrence(fullActualImage, expectedPartialImage, new OccurrenceMatchingOptions()
                    .withEnabledVisualization());
    assertThat(result.getVisualization().length, is(greaterThan(0)));
    assertNotNull(result.getRect());
```

But I'm facing **No route found for /session/48cb46ad-f1ab-42c2-97e0-6aab7117705a/appium/compare_images** in console of appium

I can execute my tests with appium: I'm able to perform clicks, navigate through the apps, so the session url should be ok, I've initialized it as a "http://127.0.0.1:4723"

Im expecting image comparing results and I've tried to execute an exact example from appium docs

Comment: What version of appium are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might not have activated the plugin yet.

Please refer to the official [documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/packages/images-plugin/README.md).

> Activation
>
> The plugin will not be active unless turned on when invoking the Appium server:
>
> ```
> appium --use-plugins=images
> ```